Не работают стили next.js 14
Изучаю next.js. Пытаюсь подключить локальные стили страницы. Делаю по документации https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#example.
Создал в папке страницы файл styles.module.css. Но стили почему-то не работают. Классы в devTools отображаются, но не применяются.
Чтобы не распинаться скажу только, что делаю страницу login и приложу картинку:

styles.module.css:
.main {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    background: #F5F5F5;
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
    
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.password {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px;
}

page.js:
import styles from "./styles.module.css"

const Page = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.main}>
            <div className={styles.password}>Password</div>
            <input type="password" />
            <button>Login</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Page

Облазил весь интернет, но ничего не нашёл, помогите, пожалуйста. В next я новичок, поэтому не убивайте, пожалуйста, если я буду задавать тупые вопросы.
